# Issues loading scripts in footer of a PHP CMS

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm currently working on a custom CMS, (just a basic layout split into templates, header.php, footer.php etc.).  I'm trying to avoid loading my scripts within the header, but some of them, like a jQuery plugin that populates a gallery with photos and videos, need to be loaded first.  Right now, I'm writing my functions after the loaded scripts within the footer.  It works, but it's far from optimal because not all script blocks and JS files are need for every template, but I can't seem to find a way to split script blocks between templates without loading JS within the header.  Is there a best practice for this sort of situation, or am I stuck with loading scripts within the header?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a little advice: This is hardly about a content-management-system, but rather PHP, HTML and of course JavaScript...in my opinion that is.

Answer (score 0):

For best practices, as far as I know, javascripts are ideally placed at the bottom of the page since most would only function when all elements of the page have loaded.

jQuery plugins, I have used so far work, even when placed below the main content of the HTML. Since most of these plugins are enclosed with `$(document).ready()` they won't really do anything until the page completely loads even if they were loaded in the header. The only heads up would be to place `jQuery.js` above jQuery plugin scripts for the plugins to work.